# listing parent and child values together

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has this value, where Menu_id is ID for that particular row and Parent_Menu_id is the Id, which tell the Parent Id for that value.

For example, Parent_Menu_Id is NULL for Menu_Id 2, which means, it doesn't have any parent, whereas, 3 has parent_menu_d 2, which means 3 is child of 2.

[image]

But, I'm facing one problem to display all the parent and child value together, which means output should be

```
Menu_id | Parent_Menu_id
-------------------------
2       |
3       |    2
9       |    2
4       |
5       |    4
6       |    4
7       |
8       |    7
```

I tried

```
select menu_id,parent_menu_id from menu_test mt where parent_menu_id=(select menu_id from menu_test where mt.parent_menu_id=menu_id)
```

But, in that case, I'm only getting child rows.

even I tried

```
 select distinct menu_id,parent_menu_id from menu_test CONNECT BY PRIOR menu_id=parent_menu_id order by menu_id,parent_menu_id
```

Still same problem of listing together

**Note : Both output looks same, but when you will see menu_id 9, then you will get the difference and what I want.**

Comment: :I think data mentioned by you for table menu_test is same as desired output ,then what you want in the result ,please elaborate your answer

Comment: please check menu_id 9, in both output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need ordering of all data with id and parent_id together. Just use an order by clause for this.

```
     select * from table order by  nvl(Parent_Menu_id,Menu_id),Menu_id;
```

Comment: almost, but not exactly same as I want

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5faa2/5 It gave correct result. Could you specify what difference you see.

Comment: added one more column in `ORDER BY` clause and got the exact output. :)

Comment: I guess the order inside the group differs for you. I am updating my answer with better option.

Comment: You are getting that output because, you added Menu_id 9 first, If you add it after 8, then you will see , what I'm saying. Anyway thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Yes, i saw that and modified it in sqlfiddle. Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this too,

```
SELECT menu_id, parent_menu_id
  FROM menu_test
START WITH parent_menu_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR menu_id = parent_menu_id;
```